# Runtime.exec not showing GUI in JBoss environment

Tags: java, jboss7.x, runtime.exec

There are many Q & A on Runtime.exec, but still I found a strange behavior. I am running desktop application in which jobs (a kind of javax.resource.spi.work.Work) are submitted and executed in JBoss application server. Following is the code to run some script, which is blocking whenever it needs to launch any GUI. For example, if the script or command is

```
start notepad
```

The GUI is not launched, but i can see the notepad.exe in Task Manager. I dont know what is blocking to launch the notepad GUI. Following is the code:

```
String pathString= "D:\\folder\\abcd.bat";
pro = runtime.exec(new String[] {
          pathString
        });
```

Content of abcd.bat file is

```
start notepad
```

No error logs or exception found. The above code works very well in normal Java class.

EDIT: Issue found only with .exe files which launch GUI. Some .exe which does not require launching GUI but running some background task is executed very well with my code.

EDIT: Forgot to say that my application is running as service.

Comment: Have you tried `start "" notepad`?  Could you use the [Desktop Integration API instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)?

Comment: It is not always Desktop API to use, because user may give any script (ie .bat in windows .sh in linux) path which may or may not contain executing .exe files..

Comment: start "" notepad also not working :-(

Comment: Are you reading the `InputStream` from the `Process`?

Comment: Its launching GUI when i set "Allow service to interact with desktop" option in services properties.. But how to set this programaticaly?

Comment: I would guess, you can't (or least shouldn't).  You may need to configure it as part of the installation process for the service

Comment: correct, but i wonder why there is no windows batch command to enable and disable this ? so that i can add those statements into my script file before launching any executable..

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Windows vista, services not allowed interacting with desktop. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . It is windows security restriction to not allow services to interact with desktop. I have done changes in `regedit` and Log On properties of my service, it worked well.